# How to *manually* reuse off-screen UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I use `-[UICollectionViewCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:]` to calculate size of my autolayouted cells in `-[UICollectionView collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:]`. If the cell is already on the screen I get it with `-[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:]`,  if it's not, I have to create a new one. Actually it's waste to create a new cell every time UIKit asking me for a size. Since `UICollectionView` already have cell reusing engine built in - I would like to use it. I can get a new cell with `-[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:]`, but how can I actually reuse it? How to tell `UICollectionView` I don't need this cell anymore and it could be reused?